# Sonarqube is running but web interface is not reachable

Tags: sonarqube-web

I have installed Sonarqube 5.6.7 on centos. Sonarqube is up and running fine. But web interface is not reachable (ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED), tried searching all but no solution I found.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check your firewall and proxy settings. If you are accessing it remotely then you need to update sonar.properties file.

```
sonar.web.host: 127.0.0.1 #use your server IP here
sonar.web.port: 9001 # default port 9000
```

update `sonar.core.serverBaseURL` in same file.

Try to access webui after restarting the server.

Comment: Thanks for your Solution.But in my case IPtables was blocking and cleared that and was able to access web interface.